# How to fix "ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID" error in Node.js (nestjs) TLS connection?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nestjs, tls1.2, tls1.3

I am trying to establish a TLS connection in nestjs using the tls.connect() method, but I am getting the error

> 'Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match
> certificate's altnames'

I should note that my colleague is able to successfully establish a TLS connection using the same certificate, IP address, and port number in Android Studio Java, using the Keystore tool. This suggests that the certificate itself is valid and that the issue may be specific to Node.js.
NB:

- connection should be on tls1.2v but my server works on tlsv1.3 I coudn't force it to run on tls1.2v (Itried with tls 1.2 same error)
- I'm using nodejs 14.20.0
- Latest version of nestjs
  If there are things to do before connection please tell me comments

```
const fs = require('fs');
const tls = require('tls');

const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certssl/cert.crt'),
    host: '196.xxx.xx.xx',
    port: 443,
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    maxVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
};

const connectionOperation = tls.connect(options, () => {
    if (connectionOperation.authorized) {
        console.log('Connection authorized');
        connectionOperation.write(hexString);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection not authorized');
        console.log(connectionOperation.authorizationError);
    }
});
```

LOG :

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 196.xxx.xx.xx is not in the cert's list:
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:347:12)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1525:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:709:12)
```

Comment: *"Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 196.xxx.xx.xx is not in the cert's list"* - you use an IP address as the target host. This IP address is not contained as subject alternative name in the certificate.Therefore the certificate does not match the given hostname, i.e. the certificate is not valid for the given host. Fixes need to be done on the certificate (to include the IP) or on your target host (use real hostname instead of IP address).

Comment: But my colleague  works with same credentiels, does I need something else with cert such as private Key or something else

Comment: Hard to tell why it behaves differently without seeing the exact code your colleague is using. And this is purely a mismatch between what hostnames/IP are expected in the certificate and what is actually in the certificate. It has nothing to with private key or something else.

Comment: It works on android studio java, if yo provide me your discord account I will provide you the code in java if you don't mind